# JSON camera-point structure TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, json, typeerror, ros, calibration

Currently I'm working on gathering points from a camera output. I have 4 cameras. They all need to post into the file in a structure similar to this

```
{
'camera1':data.IP,
'point:data'.point,

'camera2':data.IP,
'point:data'.point,

'camera3':data.IP,
'point:data'.point,

'camera4':data.IP,
'point:data'.point,
...........
.........
...........
}
```

If camera see a point - it should post it in a file, otherwise it post nothing and its IP and point do not appear. And we dump it into the file as long as we see points. The way I do now, it looks like a separate fragments from each camera in different parenthesis.

I was trying to make a structure, load my data into this structure and normalize it. But I have received an error:

```
data = json.loads(CAM) TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

By any chance, do you know how to solve the issue?

I'm attaching a real code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rospy
import json
from std_msgs.msg import String
from pixart.msg import raw_point
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pandas import DataFrame

def Load_file(data):
     with open('/home/ragesh/catkin_ws/src/pixart/src/data.json', 'a') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=5)  


def callback(data):
    print data
    CAM = [{'camera_id': data.camera_id,
            'point':[
                {'x':data.x},
                {'y':data.y}],
            'secs': data.stamp.secs,
            'nsecs': data.stamp.nsecs}]
   # CAM = json_normalize(CAM, 'camera_id', 'x', 'y', 'secs', 'nsecs')
    data = json.loads(CAM)
    data = json_normalize(data)

    Load_file(data)




def subscriber():
    rospy.init_node('data_store', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/pixart_raw', raw_point, callback)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        rospy.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    subscriber()
```

Comment: In `callback` convert the `CAM list` to `string` then pass it to `json.loads`, you can convert it to string by using `str(CAM)`

Comment: data = str(CAM)
    data = json.loads(data)
    data = json_normalize(data)
    data = json_normalize(data)

If it is like this, then it is not working

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: [ERROR] [1529328080.479925]: bad callback: <function callback at 0x7f2bc2d92500>

ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON because your node are duplicate,

you can do in 2 different way:

```
{
'camera1':data.IP,
'point1':data.point,

'camera2':data.IP,
'point2':data.point,

'camera3':data.IP,
'point3':data.point,

'camera4':data.IP,
'point4':data.point,
...........
.........
...........
}
```

or

```
[  {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"},  {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"},  {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"},   {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"}  ]
```

Example of how to add element to this JSON:

```
a=[  {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"},  {"camera":"data.IP","point":"data.point"}] #declare my dictionary
print (a) #print my dictionary
a.append({"test":1}) #add element to dictionary
print (a) #print again the dictionary that will contain my new element
```

OTHER EXAMPLE (this could be different if the data structure is different):

```
def callback(data):
    #I create many list for each variable
    ids=[]
    x=[]
    y=[]
    secs=[]
    nsecs=[]
    #I introduce in my lists all the values
    ids.append(data.camera_id)
    x.append(data.x)
    y.append(data.y)
    secs.append(data.stamp.secs)
    nsecs.append(data.stamp.nsecs)
    CAM=[]
    #I create a loop for each camera id and for each element I create a new line regarding the specific camera in CAM
    i=0
    while i<len(ids):
        CAM.append({'camera_id': ids[i],'point':[{'x':x[i]},{'y':y[i]}],'secs': secs[i],'nsecs': nsecs[i]})
        i+=1
    data = json.loads(CAM)
    data = json_normalize(data)

    Load_file(data)
```

Comment: but that's the point, one in a time I receive 1 structure like this: ['camera':data.IP,'point':data.point],
How should I append it in a main one: {
['camera':data.IP,'point':data.point],

['camera':data.IP,'point':data.point],

['camera':data.IP,'point':data.point],

['camera':data.IP,'point':data.point],
...........
.........
...........
}

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko I edited my answer because I made i parenthesis mistake while I was writing. Anyway if you are in the 2 case it will behave as a list so you do an .append({"new_camera":"camera_value", "new_point":"point_value"})

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko I added an example on my answer, if you want use a different structure let me know and I'll help you, you have different way to structure your JSON

Comment: for example, I do have this structure:
 CAM = [{'camera_id': data.camera_id,
            'point':[
                {'x':data.x},
                {'y':data.y}],
            'secs': data.stamp.secs,
            'nsecs': data.stamp.nsecs}]

but it keep posting result as: 
[{
***
}]
[{
***
}]
and not [{
***
***
}]

Comment: it's normal, it can't be all together because you can't have mode nodes with the same name in the same dictionary{}. It will work without problem if it will be [{...},{...}] when you need get the data you just do a loop on the JSON and for each iteration you can get the 'camera_id', 'point', etc...

Comment: if you give me an example of DATA that u pass to the function callback() I'll make for u a code example and I'll explain u ;)

Comment: Yeah, sure, would be great. 
x: 256
y: 755
camera_id: 0
point_id: 0
stamp: 
  secs: 1529328378
  nsecs:  97636715
x: 247
y: 757
camera_id: 0
point_id: 0
stamp: 
  secs: 1529328378
  nsecs: 101306158

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko could u please give me more set of data and tell me the structure that you pass to them? is it a dictionary, list, list of dictionary...... because based on the structure you will have to make a look in a different way

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko adding on my answer one of the example, but depending of the data structure passed to callback() the function can change

Comment: Carlo, as it is a program for ROS we are accepting a data from another program that publish it in a structure defined in a message. do our data will have next fields: 
uint16 x; uint16 y; uint16 camera_id; uint8 point_id; time stamp. It will be received as a list.

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko so the example that I wrote in the post should work even if it can be improved ;)

Comment: No, sorry, even if I do this:
CAM = []
CAM.append({{'camera_id': data.camera_id, 'point':[ {'x':data.x}, {'y':data.y}], 'secs': data.stamp.secs, 'nsecs': data.stamp.nsecs}}) 

it is printing like [{}][{}][{}][{}][{}] and not [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: @OlenaHryshaienko you are messing up with parenthesis: CAM.append({'camera_id': data.camera_id, 'point':[ {'x':data.x}, {'y':data.y}], 'secs': data.stamp.secs, 'nsecs': data.stamp.nsecs})